Why does the state transition matrix of a Discrete-PI controller have a real eigenvalue at 1 when $K_I = 0$?
I am working with the state-space representation of a PI controller for a system with a 1-step delay. When the integral gain $K_I$ is set to zero, the controller effectively becomes proportional-only. Under these conditions, I notice that the state transition matrix always has a real eigenvalue at $1 + 0j$ even the $K_P$ lower than ultimate gain and the system do converge ($e$ converge to 0).
Base equation
$$
[]=[−1]−[−2]
$$
$$
[]=[−1]+_0 []+_1 [−1]                                 
$$
$$
[]=(_0+_1 )[−1]+[−1]−_0 [−2]
$$
State vector:
$$
x[k] = \begin{bmatrix}
e[k] \\
u[k] \\
u[k-1]
\end{bmatrix}
$$
State transition equation:
$$
x[k] = \mathbf{A} x[k-1]
$$
where:
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -k \\
(b_0 + b_1) & 1 & -b_0 k \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
b_0 = K_P+K_iT/2
$$
$$
b_1 = -K_P+K_iT/2
$$
When $K_I = 0$, the coefficients simplify to $b_1 = 0$, and the eigenvalue $1$ always appears.
Why does this happen, and what is the mathematical or control-theoretic reasoning behind this eigenvalue being $1$ when there is no integral gain?
Pole location on z-plane

I used numpy.linalg.eig to find eigenvalue od state stransition matrix.
Unit step response


What software and command did you use to plot the pole locations? Also when $Ki = 0$, isnt $b1 = -Kp \neq 0$ ?

I use python and matrix eigenvalue. $b1 = -K_P$ indeed

Please use the [edit] option below the question to add the above clarifications directly into the question as they are quite relevant.


I use python and matrix eigenvalue

The the integration / accumulation occurs in the equation $[]=[−1]−[−2]$. This appears in the first row of the matrix $A$ and is not affected by either the gain $K1$ or $K2$. Those gains only say if the output of the integrator influences the state $u$.
The system dynamics (represented by $A$) still contains the eigen value of $1+0i$. It is just that it is "un observable" at the output $u[k]$. If  you model the input and output matrices $B$ and $C$ for the system and do the Python equivalent of "pzmap()" from Matlab / GNU Octave, you will be able to notice that the pole / eigen value at $1+0i$ is cancelled exactly by a "zero" at 1+0i.

But with some initial condition like $[1,0,0]^{T}$ the system experience "steady state error" behaiover. Isn't that relate to some hidden variable encoded to my choice of state variable? Forexample, some initial might equivalent to constant distuurbance to the system.

I am guessing that since $Ki=0$ disconnects the input to the integrator, the integrator state will remain constant and result in the steady state error. But the good news is that this state is a variable inside your controller and you can decide what its initial condition is.

So, to summaries, the state vector already include the state of integrator. some intialize result in not zero initial value of this integretor result in steady state and eigval at (1+0j)

If is possible please you the math derrivation to explain this. maybe the equivalent of initial integrator value and its effect on output. I would really appretiate that and I will try to solve it myself in the mean time.
